# SelectOneMenu width not working using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, jsf-2

I'm using selectOneMenu JSF 2 and trying to change the width of it is not working.

```
`<h:selectOneMenu style="width:280px" styleClass="selectpicker"`>
            <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="A" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="B" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="C " />
        </h:selectOneMenu>`
```

Only works when I remove the `styleClass = "selectpicker"`

I've already tried adding the data-width, it also did not work. Any tips?

Comment: Hey guys, any tips ???

Comment: @Kukeltje, I did not understand your repost, did you just come to teach me how to post on the forum or heal my doubts?

Answer (score 0):

The selectpicker should be having its own css properties set which is stopping the width style from being applied. Can you paste the properties set inside the selectpicker.

Comment: Hi Ragu, How would you put inside the selectpicker?  Already add: "data-width", "style="width:", not working.

Comment: What is the css written on the class styleClass="selectpicker"`. If the width is set inside this selectpicker css class, then you need to check on how you can override as stakahop pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Find a css class of h:selectOneMenu component in inspect element and override it in your custom css file.

Eg.

```
.selectOneMenuClassName{
    width:280px !important;
}
```

Just find a right class name.

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear what is inside selectpicker css class. To make it work, first selectpicker should be the css class and second there should be no css error inside it. But if you want to change the width for all the selectonemenu on your page, this may be helpful if anybody still needed !

```
.ui-selectonemenu{
  width: 280px !important;
}

.ui-selectonemenu-label{
  width: 280px !important;
}

.ui-selectonemenu-panel {
  width:280px !important;
}
```

Comment: The question is about a `h:selectOneMenu` not a PrimeFaces one.